# Powershell Variable data from Functions being lost

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script and along the way collect data in a $message variable.

The very first line in my script is:

```
$message="Server Validation script run on server $ComputerName at "
```

And this is all that is output.

In my Functions I have:

```
$startservice=Start-Service $ServiceName
$message+="$ServiceName is not running attemting to start"
```

While the function does the work it doesn't not append the message to the $message Variable when used in a loop.  Example
    ForEach($servicename in $services) {
    FuncCheckService $ServiceName
    }

What can I do so that I can collect data in my variables?

Comment: I see that you updated your question after I posed an answer. Was there some issue with the answer provided?

Comment: NO, I think I updated the question as you were answering it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the function works in a separate workspace than the rest of the script. What you may want to do is change that last line to:

```
Write-Output "$message$ServiceName is not running attemting to start"
```

Then when you call the function you can do:

```
$Message = StartServiceFunction
```

And then $Message captures any output from the function, which would be the message you wanted to pass.

Or just have the function pass the service that isn't running and attempting to start, and run it as $Message += Function such as:

```
$startservice=Start-Service $ServiceName
Write-Output "$ServiceName is not running attemting to start"
ForEach($servicename in $services) { $Message += FuncCheckService $ServiceName }
```

Alternatively, and I wouldn't recommend doing it this way, you could reference the global variable instead when you update it:

```
$global:message+="$ServiceName is not running attemting to start"
```

That will update the $message variable outside of the function.

Comment: What is the reasoning against recommending Global Variables?

Comment: because functions don't usually alter things outside of themselves and just return data either down the pipe or to display or to put into a variable. It also makes it harder to keep track of where variables are being updated

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get your desired result is to return a value from `FuncCheckService` function and then append that to `$message`.
The result will echo contents of `$message` at the end:

```
$message="Server Validation script run on server $ComputerName at "
function FuncCheckService($ServiceName){
    $startservice=Start-Service $ServiceName
    return "$ServiceName is not running attemting to start"
}
ForEach($servicename in $services) { $message+= (FuncCheckService $ServiceName) }
$message
```